# Swift generic method not working with optional downcast

Tags: xcode, generics, swift, ios8, afnetworking-2

Using AFNetworking I'm trying to parse JSON and create some model objects. I pass a dictionary to my modal object's initializer and let it configure itself like so:

```
public class ModalObject: NSObject {

    public var area: String?

    init(data: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        if let area: AnyObject = data["Area"] {
            self.area = area as? String
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine, but as I'm assigning a few properties I though I could extract this code into a generic method. My attempt at a generic method looks like this:

```
class func valueForDictionaryKey<T>(key :String, dictionary :Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) -> T? {
    if let value: AnyObject = dictionary[key] {
        return value as? T
    }

    return nil
}
```

which I was hoping would allow me to write the following in the initializer:

```
self.area = ModalObject.valueForDictionaryKey("Area", dictionary: data)
```

However, this doesn't seem to work as the optional downcast always returns nil.

Am I doing something wrong in my generic method?

Comment: I'm not at my Mac right now, so I can't test it, but I have a hunch that using `Any` as the type in your `if-let` may fix your issue, since String is a value type (and thus not an `AnyObject`) in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

- https://github.com/dankogai/swift-json/

BTW JSON and static typing do not get along very well.  Generics are for static typing while JSON is dynamic.

Comment: Thanks dankogai. Again, that looks very interesting but I was primarily trying to understand why my generic method doesn't work. I've updated the question title to better reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the [JSONModel](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel) pod. 
You can find [here](http://www.jsonmodel.com/) the documentation and samples. It mentions `Data models that take care of: Input Validation, Type Casting, Class Cascading & more. Automatically.` which might save you some time in the near-future.
As mentioned on the Github page, [here](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-fetch-and-parse-json-by-using-data-models/)'s a step-by-step tutorial on "How to fetch and parse JSON by using data models" which is probably what interests you.

If you haven't worked with PODs before, [here](http://blogs.triffort.com/?p=309)'s a pretty straight forward tutorial on how to set it up.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that pod looks interesting, however, I was more interested as to why my generic method doesn't work more than how to deal with the JSON as I'm primarily trying to learn Swift just now.